# Add Reference option missing from Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm using *Visualstudio 2017* and need to add a reference for `System.IO.Ports`. However I can't find the Add Reference option (in any right-click menu in the solution explorer) nor instructions on how to do this. Help please? Thank you

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out OP? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I have no memory of this. Have you tried the answer below? There's also the chance that I hadn't found a solution, installed VS2015 and followed the answer below. Sorry :/

Comment: I have tried that option to no avail. I'll try running a repair of the program to see if that helps. It's a strange problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The steps to *Add a Reference* in Visual Studio is:

1. Go to the Project option in the top toolbar.
2. Add Reference
   option(Roughly the 10th option from top).
3. In the reference
   manager choose the appropriate reference that you want.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 community edition but I believe the process is same for 2017 edition.

Comment: I *am* using VS2017, and the Project menu does not have this option. (screenshot here: (https://imgur.com/a/GB1nO))

Comment: Same problem here, I do not see the option to add reference anywhere at all.

Comment: The options available on the menu Project will vary according to the object which is currently selected on the Solution Explorer. This answer is missing a step "0. Select References for your project on Solution Explorer".  But anyway, the option Add Reference will only be there if the project is a .NetFramework (not .Net Core), as RedApe pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 10):

When you create a new project you can choose several templates of c# application.
If you select "Console App (.NET Framework)" you will be able to add references
But if you select "Console App (.NET Core)" there will be no reference tab

After project is created you can check it via "Project properties"  / Application / Target Framework:

".NET Core 2.0" (has no references)
or ".NET Framework 4.6.1" (has preferences)

As far as I understand in your case the most simple solution is to create new project and to copy you code into it.

Comment: I had same issue and solved it by recreating project targeted to .NET framwork instead of Core. Do you know why this is though? What if you want to add references in a .NET Core project?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used NuGet Packages. This solution is half working, but you can add reference to most popular libraries.

[image: Ref to System.IO.Ports]