# Cannot find reference in Solution Explorer on VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I want to add `System.Data.Linq` for my database as a practice. In Microsoft docs, it make a suggestion about the adding `System.Data.Linq`:

- In Solution Explorer, right-click References, and then click Add Reference.
- In the Add Reference dialog box, click .NET, click the `System.Data.Linq` assembly, and then click OK.
- The assembly is added to the project.

But the problem is I cannot find reference on the Solution Explorer.

I found a question on Stack Overflow, and there is an answer that said:

"Reason you are only getting those three options is because you are in Folder View. You can switch your view from Folder View to Solution View which will give you the menu you are looking for to add the Reference to a Project."

Like this:

[image: image 1]

But my Solution Explorer is like this:

[image: image 2]

It is the "Switch between solution and available views" not "Folder View".

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of .net are you using?

Comment: I think is Core 2.1

Comment: In that case you can probably install the library you want via Nuget - assuming the same library exists in Core. I think the instructions you found were probably for .NET Framework

Comment: Try this link to add a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364730/add-reference-option-missing-from-solution-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364730/add-reference-option-missing-from-solution-explorer)